# Compare file to list and copy accordingly

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have a script that I am using to compare and sort the files in two directories.  I am currently trying to compare all of the files in one directory to a list of files in the other, and then copy those files into a "match" or "unique" directory.

I've managed to match the file name against the list and then copy the file, but I can't quite get it to copy that file into a target directory while keeping the name.

Here is what I have:

```
input2_only = [file1.mp3, file2.mp3, etc]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("input2", topdown=False):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        if filename in input2_only:
            print('yay')
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), "outputs")
```

I think there is something that I can change in the shutil line to make this work, but every tweak I've tried so far has lead to heartache. Just to be clear, in this snippet I want it to copy the file being compared against the list to a directory called "outputs".  Once I can do that I'm reasonably confident I can fill in the rest of the logic.

thanks!

Comment: Are the two source directories flat, i.e. no nested directories?

Comment: Yes. Source directories are flat and output directories are flat.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out and posting in case it is helpful to someone else.  The key is creating the output target before calling shutil.  The correct snippet is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("input2", topdown=False):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        if filename in input2_only:
            print('yay')
            out = "outputs/" + filename
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), out)
```

that "out" line makes the target of the shutil output the name of the file in the folder "outputs"